# Mapbox GL JS: filter features by input text

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Context:

- Angular 6
- Mapbox GL JS - v0.51 (limited to the @types/mapbox-gl-js version)

I know for now Mapbox GL JS no support the filter contain/includes expression for string values (here is a summary of that subject https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6484)

Is there a way to emulate this behavior ?

I used to have a GeoJSON source:

```
this._map.addSource('geojson-source', {
      type: 'geojson',
      data: geojson,
    });
```

The GeoJSON was coming from an ElasticSearch query, and I could filter "on the fly" by doing another query, and re-render the source and all the layers.

The problem is for big datasets (around 100k points). It's too slow.

So now we want use a MVT vector source

```
this._map.addSource('vector-source', {
      type: 'vector',
      data: urlVector,
    });
```

And we use this expression to filter by input text:

```
filter: ['match', ['get', property], this.filterSearch, true, false]);
```

The problem now is the expression 'match' is too restrictive

eg.: 'Platanus' will match all Platanus trees, but 'Platan' will find nothing.

I see that Github issues are open for 2 years now for this subject on Mapbox GL JS (the Android and iOS version have these filters working already).

In all your projects, how guys did you find a way to hack/emulate this kind of behavior ?

Did you find a way, or did you give up the filter ? ^^

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, I think you're asking for a way to build a filter based on partial string matches: the equivalent of a `^Platan` regular expression. As you noted, there is no built in mechanism for this.

One work-around would be to transform the dataset at the time you receive it to either generate substrings, or split the string into individual characters:

```
properties: {
  species: 'Platanus',
  species0: 'P',
  species1, 'l',
...

}
```

Then your filter would be:

```
filter: ['==', 'Platan', ['concat',
  ['get', 'species0'],
  ['get', 'species1'],
  ['get', 'species2'],
  ['get', 'species3'],
  ['get', 'species4'],
  ['get', 'species5']
]]
```

Obviously it's ugly, but that's the nature of a workaround.